# IOS/Objective-C: Subview of Subview not displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, addsubview

I am trying to create a chart where a bar in the form of a UIView displays on top of a background UIView.  I'd like both to display on top of the UIView for the whole screen.  I have done this before successfully, but while I can get the first view to display, I somehow can't get my code to display the bar.  Could it have something to do with setting the color?  Or can anyone suggest why the second subview is not displaying.

My code:

```
//Make background box:  
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat graphWidth = screenWidth-40;
    CGFloat graphHeight = 160;
      CGRect graphBounds =CGRectMake(20, 200, graphWidth, graphHeight);
    float tableStartY = graphBounds.origin.y;

    UIView *graphBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:graphBounds];
    graphBox.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:200.0/255.0 green:200.0/255.0 blue:200.0/255.0 alpha:0.2]; graphBox.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    graphBox.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

//Make Bar

    CGFloat barWidth = 20;
    CGFloat barHeight = 100;
    CGRect aBar = CGRectMake(20, tableStartY+1, barWidth, barHeight);
    UIView *barView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:aBar];
   barView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    barView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    barView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

   // [graphBox addSubview:barView];
    [self.view addSubview: graphBox];
```

If I run the above code, it displays the graphBox.  If I add the bar directly to the view as a subView instead of the graphBox, the bar displays.  However, if I uncomment out the line shown and add the barView first to the graphBox and then add the graphBox to the view, the barView does not display.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: seems youre missing a strong reference for the bar and it gets deallocated immediately

Comment: @user6631314 I try your code. It works well. See screen shot https://ibb.co/jcPxwU. The barView could be shown on the screen.

Comment: As already mentioned, barView shows correctly, but you are making a mistake in calculating its frame by assigning it absolute instead of relative coordinates, so it is drawn outside graphBox. You can see it by replacing [graphbox addSubView:barView] with [self.view addSubView:barView] and moving it AFTER [self.view addSubView:graphBox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you need to do, you should replace

```
CGRect aBar = CGRectMake(20, tableStartY+1, barWidth, barHeight);
```

with

```
CGRect aBar = CGRectMake(20, 1, barWidth, barHeight);
```

[edit: and obviously uncomment the addSubview line]

Comment: Yes.  That was it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is an accident in your posted code, but you have specifically commented out where the `barView` would be added to the screen.

```
   // [graphBox addSubview:barView];
```

In addition, as [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51824466/2708650) lists, your offset is incorrect if you are adding `barView` to `graphBox`. If you add it to `self.view` instead, your offset is correct.

So, you've got two choices, depending on the containment you desire in your view hierarchy:

```
CGRect aBar = CGRectMake(20, 1, barWidth, barHeight);
// ...
[graphBox addSubview:barView];
```

or

```
CGRect aBar = CGRectMake(20, tableStartY+1, barWidth, barHeight);
// ...
[self.view addSubview: graphBox];
[self.view addSubview:barView];
```

Note that in the second option, the order is important to get the `barView` to display over top of the `graphBox` as they will be siblings.

Comment: He explained "However, if I uncomment out the line shown and add the barView first to the graphBox and then add the graphBox to the view, the barView does not display." (however this happens not to be the case: the barview appears *outside* the box)